# What is the flaw in the following logic?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to solve the [secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem).

As is known, I am assuming that the optimal strategy belongs to the class of strategies where we observed the first $k$ candidates and choose the first candidates that is better than all the first $k$ candidates. We first need to calculate the probability of the event that we find the best candidate if we follow this strategy.

My strategy is as following:

1. We cannot select the best candidate if the best candidate is among the first $k$ candidates. This can occur with probability $\frac{k}{n}$.
2. Assume that the best candidate among the first $k$ candidate is the $i^{th}-$ranked candidate. The probability of this event is $$\frac{{{n-i}\choose{k-1}}}{{n} \choose k}$$
3. Lets compute the probability of the event that the best candidate is the first one who occurs after $k$ candidates and better than all the $k$ candidates given that the best candidates among the first $k$ candidates is the $i^{th}-$ranked candidate. Since there are total $i - 1$ candidates who are better than all the candidates in the first $k$. The probability that the best candidate appears before them is 
   $$
   \frac{1}{i -1}
   $$
4. Our desired probability is 
   $$
   \sum_{i=2}^{n-k+1} \frac{{{n-i}\choose{k-1}}}{{n} \choose k} \frac{1}{i -1}
   $$

This quantity should be equal to the answer given in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) that is $\frac{k}{n}\sum_{i=k +1}^{n} \frac{1}{i - 1}$.

> Based on the Bof's suggestions, I corrected the above equations. I am still not able to show that my equations is same as the article equations for  all $k\geq 1$. Concretely we need to show the following:
>   $$
> \sum_{i=2}^{n-k+1} \frac{{{n-i}\choose{k-1}}}{{n} \choose k} \frac{1}{i -1} = \frac{k}{n}\sum_{i=k +1}^{n} \frac{1}{i - 1}.
> $$
>
> **For k = 1**, it is obviously true.
>   $$
> LHS = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=2}^{n} \frac{1}{i-1} = RHS
> $$
>
> **For k=2**, the equations are correct.
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> LHS &=& \frac{2}{n(n-1)}\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{n-i}{i-1}\\
> &=& \frac{2}{n(n-1)}\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\left(\frac{n-1}{i-1} - 1\right)\\
> &=& \frac{2}{n}\left(\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i-1} - 1 + \frac{1}{n -1} \right)\\
> &=&\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=3}^{n}\frac{1}{i-1}\\
> &=&RHS
> \end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the above identity as a separate questions. The answers can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404287/how-to-solve-the-following-identity).